# SharePoint 2010 How can I efficiently get all employees to read and Accept on a policy?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, infopath

How can I efficiently get all employees to read and Accept on a policy?

We have certain policies that need to be read and accepted on by ALL employees

Need to be able to track who has "Read" the policy; And track the users who have Not completed the request.

Users "who have not Read the Policy"  get "Alerts" to read the policy

Comment: How many employees are we talking about?

Comment: I have not used this product, merely read some stuff on their blog, but it may be worth a look: http://www.collaboris.com/products/policy-and-procedure-management-software

Comment: over 400 employees; I have looked into DocReader (they are expensive); trying to find out if I could create something

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution could be:

Develop a **custom _layouts page** (foundation) or **info path form** (enterprise edition) with the complete policy information at the top like a paragraph control and with a checkbox at the bottom to acknowledge/read the policy. provide a submit button to confirm.

add an entry to the custom list with the user name (captured via SPContext in WSS object model) along with the time stamp (you can use the created field).

This way you will be able to capture and create a report for all the users.